# Restarting Graphics after switching between onboard and dedicated graphics card

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

I am using Intel onboard graphics and nvidia geforce MX130 dedicated graphics card. In some cases I need to switch between the cards during the work on ubuntu 20.04. In Nvidia settings there is a prime profile where my graphics setting can be seen as below.

[image]

1. But without restarting how can I enable the change done here.
2. Also here Nvidia(performace Mode) and on demand option is seen. Whats the difference between two.

Comment: I assume 'Performance Mode' means the dedicated GPU is always active. 'On Demand' means that the integrated GPU is normally used unless graphically-intensive apps are used, in which case the system automatically switches to the dedicated GPU.

Comment: Why not just leave the Nvidia in Performance Mode? Use `nvidia-smi` to see the differences between modes. Use `Firefox` during the testing.

Comment: How can we enable the service change without restarting OS ?

Comment: You can't. It rebuilds /boot/initrd.img* ram disk, and requires a restart to stick.